# How to set an intelliSense of strings to avoid typing invalid values in JavaScript with VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, jsdoc

I found a cool intelliSense feature when I write the built-in keyword `typeof` in VS Code,
It shows a specific options list which contains all valid values that `typeof` returns as the picture below.

[image: It shows a specific options list]

### [image]

This feature make us avoid typing an invalid result when we use the function.

So I'm wondering that can we use jsdoc or eslint to create an intelliSense for a custom function or array? If not, is there any another tool to achieve that?

```
var dayOptions = [
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday'
]

function checkDay(option){ // I don't want to let user input values outside the array above
  // code
}

checkDay('Friday') // I want to make an intelliSense list here
checkDay('other') // I want VS Code show me something wrong here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JSDoc syntax:

```
@param {'Monday' | 'Tuesday' | 'Wednesday' | 'Thursday' | 'Friday'} option
```

[image]

> Argument of type '"other"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Monday" | "Tuesday" | "Wednesday" | "Thursday" | "Friday"'.

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what I want, THANKS!